# Navwalker won't accept css classes defined in menu

Tags: wordpress, flexbox, bulma

So I'm using the Bulma Framework w/ a Bulma Navwalker - The problem that I'm having is that it won't accept my custom css classes defined inside my WordPress menus.

So I have a is-mega class define inside one of my parent menu items, and it's not showing up under "navbar-item has-dropdown is-hoverable".

[image]

Does anyone see that I might be missing?

Here is the Navwalker:

```
<?php
/**
 * Bulma-Navwalker
 *
 * @package Bulma-Navwalker
 */

/**
 * Class Name: Navwalker
 * Plugin Name: Bulma Navwalker
 * Plugin URI:  https://github.com/Poruno/Bulma-Navwalker
 * Description: An extended Wordpress Navwalker object that displays Bulma framework's Navbar https://bulma.io/ in Wordpress.
 * Author: Carlo Operio - https://www.linkedin.com/in/carlooperio/, Bulma-Framework
 * Author URI: https://github.com/wp-bootstrap
 * License: GPL-3.0+
 * License URI: https://github.com/Poruno/Bulma-Navwalker/blob/master/LICENSE
 */

class Navwalker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {

    public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {

        $output .= "<div class='navbar-dropdown'>";
    }

    public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        $liClasses = 'navbar-item ';

        $hasChildren = $args->walker->has_children;
        $liClasses .= $hasChildren? " has-dropdown is-hoverable": "";

        if($hasChildren){
            $output .= "<div class='".$liClasses."'>";
            $output .= "\n<a class='navbar-link' href='".$item->url."'>".$item->title."</a>";
        }
        else {
            $output .= "<a class='".$liClasses."' href='".$item->url."'>".$item->title;
        }

        // Adds has_children class to the item so end_el can determine if the current element has children
        if ( $hasChildren ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'has_children';
        }
    }

    public function end_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ){

        if(in_array("has_children", $item->classes)) {

            $output .= "</div>";
        }
        $output .= "</a>";
    }

    public function end_lvl (&$output, $depth = 0, $args = array()) {

        $output .= "</div>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I would ask the Bulma developers, since it doesn't look like the Navwalker is adding the menu item classes to the `$liClasses` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by adjusting your walker slightly.  Bulmapress removes the standard classes from the walker so it can use its own.  By adding this, it will allow you to add your custom classes from the Appearance->Menu.

```
<?php

public function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

        // Add your custom item classes here
        
        $custom_classes_from_menu = implode(' ', $item->classes); // turn the WP classes object array to string values
    
        $liClasses = 'navbar-item ' . $custom_classes_from_menu; // add the values to your classes list

        $hasChildren = $args->walker->has_children;
        $liClasses .= $hasChildren? " has-dropdown is-hoverable": "";

        if($hasChildren){
            $output .= "<div class='".$liClasses."'>";
            $output .= "\n<a class='navbar-link' href='".$item->url."'>".$item->title."</a>";
        }
        else {
            $output .= "<a class='".$liClasses."' href='".$item->url."'>".$item->title;
        }

        // Adds has_children class to the item so end_el can determine if the current element has children
        if ( $hasChildren ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'has_children';
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks so much DubVader! This works perfectly - Do you by any chance have a good lead on making wordpress mega menus using Bulma?

Comment: No problem.  There is a Bulma extension that may work for your needs.  Without knowing specifics it's hard to understand exactly how to implement but this should help: https://github.com/hunzaboy/bulma-megamenu